# Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name with For Loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to create this loop but I keep getting "Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name" and not for sure where I am going wrong or how to fix this error. TIA :)

Prompt: Now let's write a for loop that will sum up the run time of the movies in 'Post Production'. Function inside the for loop will check that the movie is in Post Production, and if it is, it will add the run time of that movie to a running total of movie run times.

```
sum= 0
   for (row in 1:nrow(movies)) {
   if (row$status == "Post Production") {
   sum <- sum + row$runtime
      }
      }
```

Comment: `row` is an integer, it can not have a `status` element. Maybe you want `movies$status[row]`. Try to vectorize your code using `sum(movies$runtime[movies$status == "Post Production"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

row is an integer with values between 1 and the number of rows in your dataframe movies (because you defined it as taking values in '1:nrow(movies)').
Thus row$status is equivalent to write 1$status.
I guess that what you want to do is:

```
sum= 0
   for (row in 1:nrow(movies)) {
     if (movies$status[row] == "Post Production") {
       sum <- sum + row$runtime
     }
   }
```

here movies$status[row] will access successively the first, second, third,... element of the column 'status'